# Turn syntax highlighting off in diff mode when started within vim?

Tags: vimdiff, syntax

I would like syntax to be turned off when I am in diff mode to focus only on the differences. I have the following code in my `vimrc` which **works only** when I start vim in diff mode from the command line :

```
if &diff
    syntax off
endif
```

```
$ vim -d file1 file2 # works
```

But when I already have a file opened(`file1`) and would like to diff it with another file(`file2`) using the command `:diffsplit file2`, the code **doesn't work** and I have to manually turn it off.

I ran `:echo &diff` and it returned `1` meaning the code should be executed. Any ideas ? Thanks!

Comment: vimrc is sourced once upon startup. It should be obvious why it doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: use an `OptionSet diff` autocomd